# Passing the variable whose value can change every time, from a php page to another

Tags: php

I have a form from which i'm getting the values of two variables say username and password using POST method.

```
$Username=$_POST['Username'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];
```

I tried passing these variables to another php page using the following code.

```
<a href="abc.php?Username=$Username & Password=$Password">Click here</a>
```

In the other page,i tried printing the variable as follows.

```
$User=$_GET['Username'];
echo $USer;
```

But,I didn't get the value stored in the varible. Instead,its printing "$Username" as the value as given in the anchor tag.

I just need to print the value stored in the variable $Username.

Please, help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<a href="abc.php?Username=$Username & Password=$Password">Click here</a>` is no PHP code.

Comment: is address bar showing correct `username` value?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the following:

```
<a href="abc.php?Username=<?php echo $Username; ?>&Password=<?php echo $Password; ?>">Click here</a>
```

Although you should be careful if the variables contain special characters. So I'd advise using:

```
<?php echo urlencode($Username); ?>

<?php echo urlencode($Password); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't indicated that this is PHP code, `$Username` is interpreted as HTML, resulting in `$Username` as output. In order to output the actual value, you should add the appropriate tags, for example like this:

```
<a href="abc.php?Username=<?php echo $Username; ?> & Password=<?php echo $Password; ?>">Click here</a>
```

By the way, given your code, you are not expected to `echo` anything, since variables are case sensitive in PHP, so `$USer` in your `echo` and `$User` the line before are two distinct variables.

Also note that:

- You shouldn't pass passwords through URIs in the first place,
- You don't seem to escape input,
- The whitespace before and after "&" character in the `href` attribute may not be what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell that $Username is actually a PHP variable, and not a HTML CDATA string. Convert your link code to:

```
<a href="abc.php?Username=<?php echo $Username; ?>&Password=<?php echo $Password; ?>">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you put them in a session.

You can make it like this:

```
$Username=$_POST['Username'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];

session_start():
$Username = $_SESSION['usernameSession'];
$Password = $_SESSION['passwordSession'];
```

In the other page just call the session

```
session_start();

echo ".$_SESSION['usernameSession']";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you add some more context to your answer, for the benefit of the OP?  Namely, why do you think using the session like this is better?